# Returning Custom object which implements List<> in Web Service

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, web-services

I have been tasked to write a new web service with returns list of Addresses.

To do so I have created a class as follows:

```cs
 [Serializable]
public class AddressDataCollection : List<AddressData>
{
    private long m_ErrorCode;

    private string m_ErrorMessage;

    public long ErrorCode
    {
        get
        {
            return m_ErrorCode;
        }
        set
        {
            m_ErrorCode = value;
        }

    }

    public string ErrorMessage
    {
        get
        {
            return m_ErrorMessage;
        }
        set
        {
            m_ErrorMessage = value;
        }
    }
}
```

I have a web service function with returns this object.

```cs
    [WebMethod]
     public AddressDataCollection FastFindLookup(string strAddress, int MaxWaitTimeInMilliSeconds)
    {
    }
```

However when I try to consume this object in my client application, the visual studio code generator returns AddressData[] and discards ErrorCode, ErrorMessage props.

I am using asp.net 2.0 for client and service.

Am I missing something?

Comment: I suggest you post the exact error message here as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can either have the list of AddressData as a property, or implement IXmlSerializable and roll your own serialization. Probably the first way is easiest.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't do this. You will have to create a class that contains the list and the two properties, and serialize that.